# Getting FRACTIONAL difference (YEARS) between two dates in T SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to detect a difference between two dates, such that when `Date_1 = 12-jan-2010` and `Date_2 = 01-jan-2016` I would **NOT** get 6 but a number < 6.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(YEAR,'12-jan-2010','01-jan-2016')
```

`DATEDIFF` returns 6 in the above case.

Comment: please give an example including your expected result

Comment: Have you considered how leap years should factor into your requirement? E.g. for two dates within a single year, the difference between them should presumably be `number of days/(365 or 366)`. But over multiple years, some of which may be leap years, it's unclear what the divisor "should" be.

Comment: Show us the code that returns the unexpected result.

Comment: I apologize for disappointing those asking for details, but the question is quite clear. Here is another example: `difference between '15-sep-2016' and 16-sep-2015` should give a number **LESS THAN** 1. I'm only interested to know if the time between two dates is less than a given number of years (1 in this last example).

Comment: You have still not showed us how you use `DATEDIFF`!

Comment: What's the expected result for the period 29-feb-2016 to 28-feb-2017?

Comment: @jarlh your second question is a good one. I don't know the answer. The first is like the example from K.K.: `SELECT DATEDIFF(YEAR,'12-jan-2010','01-jan-2016')`. I know it only returns the difference in the YEAR field and hence is not the correct solution. I'm looking for the correct solution.

Comment: By the way, I just checked `select dateadd(year,1,'29-feb-2016');` and it returns `28-feb-2017`, so I guess this answers your question.

Comment: "I'm only interested to know if the time between two dates is less than a given number of years" - that's a completely different question which actually has an easy answer. *add* the given number of years onto the earlier of the two dates and then just compare that result to the later date.

Comment: I'd say date 2017-02-28  - date 2016-02-29 is 0 years. But date 2016-02-29 + 1 year is 2017-02-28. Assymetric, yes!

Comment: Wrong @jarlh, `select datediff(year,'29-feb-2016','28-feb-2017') ;` yields **1**!!!

Comment: That's the MS implementation of datediff.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on required precision, try following:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, @d1, @d2)/365.25
```

Comment: Also wrong. If no Feb. 29th in-between, the result would be wrong.

Comment: That what I said, depend on required precision. 356.25 assumes one leap year every 4 years - which is also not strict.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this resolves,

```
    DECLARE @STARTDATE DATE='12-jan-2010'
    DECLARE @ENDDATE DATE='01-jan-2016'

    DECLARE @TOTALDAY DECIMAL(18,2)=DATEDIFF(day,@STARTDATE,@ENDDATE)
    DECLARE @AVGYEAR DECIMAL(18,2)= ((365*DATEDIFF(YEAR,@STARTDATE,@ENDDATE))+
    dbo.LEAP_YEAR(@STARTDATE,@ENDDATE))/CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2),
    DATEDIFF(YEAR,@STARTDATE,@ENDDATE))

    SELECT CONVERT(decimal(18,2),@TOTALDAY/@AVGYEAR) AS DiffDate  ---This will provide you result in decimal
```

this the function which return no of leap years between dates.

```
    ALTER FUNCTION LEAP_YEAR(@START DATE,@END DATE)
    RETURNS INT
    AS BEGIN
        DECLARE @COUNT INT = 0,@Z INT = DATEPART(YYYY,@START)
        DECLARE @X INT =DATEPART(YYYY,@START)
        DECLARE @Y INT =DATEPART(YYYY,@END)

        IF (DATEPART(MM,@START) >2)
        SET @X=@X+1

        IF (DATEPART(MM,@END) <2)
        SET @Y=@Y-1

        WHILE (@X <= @Y)
        BEGIN
            SET @COUNT = @COUNT + 
                        (CASE   WHEN (@X%4 = 0 AND @X%100 !=0) OR @X%400 = 0 
                                THEN 1 
                                ELSE 0 END)
            SET @X = @X + 1
        END
        RETURN @COUNT
    END
```

Comment: Your suggestion will not work when there is a leap year in-between (or any Feb. 29th as well).

Comment: i have updated my answer based on your comment.try this.

Answer (score 0):

If I've got it right. Just Add result of DATEDIFF (`6` in this case) to the start date if it > the end date then just subtract 1 year so you will get 5 full years:

```
DECLARE @StartD DATETIME; 
DECLARE @FinalD DATETIME;

SET @StartD = '12-jan-2010';
SET @FinalD = '11-jan-2016';


SELECT DATEDIFF(YEAR,@StartD,@FinalD) 
       - CASE WHEN DATEADD(YEAR,DATEDIFF(YEAR,@StartD,@FinalD),@StartD)>@FinalD 
            THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I wish to thank all those that spent time trying to provide a simple and reliable solution. Finally, I decided to resolve it as follows:

Supposed that I want to know if `@n` full years passed between two dates, then:

```
DECLARE @n        INT      ;
DECLARE @Old_Date DATETIME ;
DECLARE @New_Date DATETIME ;

SET @n        = <some_value> ;
SET @Old_Date = <some_value> ;
SET @New_Date = <some_value> ;

IF (DATEADD(YEAR ,@n , @Old_Date) <= @New_Date)
    SET @Result = 'YES' ;
ELSE
    SET @Result = 'NO' ;
```

**[of course, a check needs to be included to verify that @Old_Date < @New_Date]**

I can't say this can be proved (mathematically) as correct in all possible scenarios, but it provides the needed answer to me.

Thanks to all again.